# How to properly set the hint of an SSBO to read and write from both shaders and cpu?

Tags: c++, opengl, runtime-error, buffer, gpu

I have a peculiar SSBO with only an int, that I need to read and write from both the shaders and the cpu.

I created said SSBO as follows:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &ssbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
glObjectLabel(GL_BUFFER, ssbo, -1, ("\"SSBO\""));
GLint zero = 0;
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(GLint), &zero, GL_STATIC_COPY);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 3, ssbo);
```

When I render, glDbeugMessage returns with:

```
OpenGL Event Notification:
Source: GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API
Type: GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PERFORMANCE
ID: Unkown error code: 131186
Severity: GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_MEDIUM
Message:
Buffer performance warning: Buffer object "SSBO" (bound to
GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, and GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER (3), usage hint is
GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW) is being copied/moved from VIDEO memory to HOST memory.
```

The most important thing in this warning is the fact that it says the SSBO has hint: `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` despite my attempt to set the hint as: `GL_STATIC_COPY`

So my question is, what hint should I use to prevent the OpenGL warning, and how do I actually enforce that hint to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a peculiar SSBO with only an int, that I need to read and write from both the shaders and the cpu.

`GL_STATIC_COPY` doesn't mean that. It means that you're only going to allocate it and write to it once (the STATIC part). And it means that it will only ever be read from/written to via GPU operations; the CPU will never manipulate the data directly (the COPY part).

So you're using the wrong hint.

> what hint should I use to prevent the OpenGL warning

If you care about this sort of thing, then you need to be using [immutable buffer allocation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Creation), not the old-style `glBufferData` stuff. "Hints" are not bindings; that's why they're "hints" and not "requirements".

`glBufferStorage` imposes *requirements*. Specifically, it imposes requirements upon your use of the memory. If you don't declare that a buffer can be mapped for reading, then you *can't* map it for reading. If you don't declare that you can write to via `glBufferSubData`, then you *can't*. Ever.

Pick the minimum set of usage requirements that you need, and work within those restrictions.

Comment: Is there a particular way that is known to make reading and writing from both the CPU and GPU to the buffer faster/better?

Comment: Performance in graphics is often based on an intimate understanding of *exactly* what you're doing. General rules can be used here and there, but real performance improvements require understanding more than just local concerns. How are you reading the buffer on the CPU? How are you writing it? How often and how much data is involved? When do these reads/writes happen, relative to the GPU modifications? And so on. Without those kinds of details, there's nothing that can be said about it.

Comment: I am writing and reading to/from it every single frame (cannot be done less). I am wrting to a single int inside an SSBO through atomic add ont he fragment shader (I am counting the number  of fragments in the current call) I am not sure what you mean by GPU modifications, and the buffer needs to be read as soon as the last fragment ended computing on the fragment shader (after teh call to glMemoryBarrier()).